# drawing part of a perfect circle using curveTo

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, drawing

I need to draw a part of a perfect circle using `graphics.curveTo` (I have the radius and the angle I want to draw) but i cant manage to understand the exact formula for the cotorol x&y in order for the curve to be perfect

I know how to do it with a loop and many `lineTo` but this is not good enough for my needs...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this function to draw circle segments (I think I ported it from an online AS2 example on how to draw full circles long ago):

```
    /**
     * Draw a segment of a circle
     * @param graphics      the graphics object to draw into
     * @param center        the center of the circle
     * @param start         start angle (radians)
     * @param end           end angle (radians)
     * @param r             radius of the circle
     * @param h_ratio       horizontal scaling factor
     * @param v_ratio       vertical scaling factor
     * @param new_drawing   if true, uses a moveTo call to start drawing at the start point of the circle; else continues drawing using only lineTo and curveTo
     * 
     */
    public static function drawCircleSegment(graphics:Graphics, center:Point, start:Number, end:Number, r:Number, h_ratio:Number=1, v_ratio:Number=1, new_drawing:Boolean=true):void
    {
        var x:Number = center.x;
        var y:Number = center.y;
        // first point of the circle segment
        if(new_drawing)
        {
            graphics.moveTo(x+Math.cos(start)*r*h_ratio, y+Math.sin(start)*r*v_ratio);
        }

        // draw the circle in segments
        var segments:uint = 8;

        var theta:Number = (end-start)/segments; 
        var angle:Number = start; // start drawing at angle ...

        var ctrlRadius:Number = r/Math.cos(theta/2); // this gets the radius of the control point
        for (var i:int = 0; i<segments; i++) {
             // increment the angle
             angle += theta;
             var angleMid:Number = angle-(theta/2);
             // calculate our control point
             var cx:Number = x+Math.cos(angleMid)*(ctrlRadius*h_ratio);
             var cy:Number = y+Math.sin(angleMid)*(ctrlRadius*v_ratio);
             // calculate our end point
             var px:Number = x+Math.cos(angle)*r*h_ratio;
             var py:Number = y+Math.sin(angle)*r*v_ratio;
             // draw the circle segment
             graphics.curveTo(cx, cy, px, py);
        }

    }
```

I think it's close enough to perfect circles. I don't really understand the math inside, but I hope the parameters are clear enough for you.

Comment: The only addition I use to the above function is to calculate the number of segments based on the arc length: `var segments = Math.ceil(Math.abs(end-start)/(Math.PI/4));`

Answer (score 3):

it would be quite difficult to create a perfect circle (or even part of one) using quadratic bezier curves, so don't feel bad.

a long awaited addition to the graphics API came in Flash Player 11 / AIR 3, which is the [cubicCurveTo()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#cubicCurveTo%28%29) function that draws cubic bezier curves, which makes drawing things like half circles especially simple.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot draw a perfect circle with Bézier curves. You only approximate it. See http://cgafaq.info/wiki/Bézier_circle_approximation.

Comment: I didn't mean drawing a perfect circle with one bazier curve. drawing a circle using multiple curves is also good. thankyou for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @YaronUliel, It's impossible even with multiple curves.