# Segmented Circle in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am looking for a way to draw, and then rotate a segmented/pie chart style circle in AS3. I'm a bit of an AS3 beginner but I have tried multiple methods but I'm getting no luck, can anyone help?

Comment: Can you add the code from your most successful method so we have something to work with?

Comment: 1. Create a triangle with linestyle | 2. Create a circle shape | 3. Set the triangle's mask to the circle created in step 2.

Comment: Use this class http://icodesnip.com/snippet/actionscript-3/as3-pie-chart I've used it and it works great

Answer (score 1):

Try my answer to this similar question: [drawing part of a perfect circle using curveTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359351/drawing-part-of-a-perfect-circle-using-curveto/10362441#10362441). That deals with the drawing part. Rotating it should be easy: change the `.rotation` property of the Sprite you've drawn the pie chart into.